# IIS Handler Mappings

Tags: iis, web-server, configuration, handler-mappings

Given multiple handler mappings are configured to handle a request, in IIS, what is the algorithm for determining which one is used to serve the response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am presuming you are asking about IIS7 Handler Mappings.

Hidden from view in IIS Manager there is a `preCondition` attribute for each handler mapping. For example here is an excerpt from `applicationHost.config` for all the different page handlers a `.aspx` page can have (I've removed some attributes to keep things concise):

```
<add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.aspx" 
     preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
<add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.aspx" 
     preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
<add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" path="*.aspx" 
     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
<add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" path="*.aspx" 
     preCondition="integratedMode" />
<add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.aspx" 
     preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
<add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0-64" path="*.aspx" 
     preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" />
```

When a `.aspx` request is passed through the IIS pipeline only the handler that matches the `preCondition` is used.

The `preConditions` generally map to the configuration of the application pool that the site or application runs in.

So if I had a site running in an application pool configured as:

```
.NET Framework Version [managedRuntimeVersion]     = v2.0
Enable 32-Bit Applications [enable32BitAppOnWin64] = True
Managed Pipeline Mode [managedPipelineMode]        = Classic
```

If `Default.aspx` was requested then the handler chosen to process this request would be:

> `PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0`

There is a great article that explains `preConditions` in much more detail here:

> [Achtung! IIS7 Preconditions](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2006/11/04/precondition-what.aspx)

I forgot to say that the order of the handler mappings is also a consideration, particularly for wildcard and extensionless mappings. The order of these can be viewed/changed in IIS Manager by opening the Handler Mappings feature for a site and then clicking on the View Ordered List link in the right hand Actions pane. In this view you can change the processing order of the handlers.